# Get primary key from INSERT INTO table_name using Spring and MyBatis web app

Tags: sql, spring, primary-key, mybatis

I am a `MyBatis` newbie and have a service class in a `Spring` and `MyBatis` application:

```
@Service("personServiceImpl")
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

@Autowired
private PersonMapper personMapper;

static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PersonServiceImpl.class.getName());

public PersonServiceImpl() { 
}

@Transactional
@Override
public void insert(Person person) {
    logger.info(PersonServiceImpl.class.getName() + ".insert() method called.");

    personMapper.insert(person);       
}
```

And in the `personMapper` object I have the following:

```
public interface PersonMapper {

@Insert("INSERT INTO Person(name, address, telephone, email) " +
        "VALUES (#{name},#{address}, #{telephone}, #{email})")          
@Options(useGeneratedKeys=true, keyProperty="Person_Id", flushCache=true, keyColumn="Person_Id")
public void insert(Person person);
```

All of which works perfectly but how can I get the primary key of the newly created row in the `Person` table?

I could do an explicit `SQL` `select` but is there a better way?

I am using `Spring 4.0.2`, `MyBatis 3.3.0` and `Apache Derby 10.x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Options(useGeneratedKeys=true, keyProperty="personId", flushCache=true, keyColumn="Person_Id")
public void insert(Person person);
```

KeyProperty refers to the POJO variable name and KeyColumn refers to generated column name in database.
Hence update it to

```
personId
```

After insert,

```
@Transactional @Override public void insert(Person person) { logger.info(PersonServiceImpl.class.getName() + ".insert() method called."); personMapper.insert(person); 
person.getPersonId();
}
```

will have your generated ID.

Comment: One issue: if my `insert` is declared in class `public interface PersonMapper` where should I call  `person.getPersonId()`?

Comment: `person.getPersonId();` does not produce the key when used like this.